# How to rewrite differential equation $x' = x-y-x\sqrt{x^2+y^2}, y' = x+y-y\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have to rewrite the differential equation:
$$x' = x-y-x\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$
$$ y' = x+y-y\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$
in the form $u' = f(u)$ with $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$

How can I do this? Can somebody explain me how I can rewrite this. Because I don't know how to start in combination with that square root

Comment: Try taking $u = (u_1,u_2)$ with $u_1 = x$ and $u_2 = y$. Now $f_1$ will be the right hand side of the first equation and so on. As for solving it: try to rewrite it in terms of polar coordinates $x(t) = r(t)\sin(\theta(t))$ and $y(t) = r(t)\sin(\theta(t))$. The resulting equations for $r$ and $\theta$ are much easier to solve.

Comment: Ah yes, polar coordinates is a great way to rewrite this system of differential equations. Thank you @Winther

Comment: @Moo Yes. Thanks!

Comment: Or with $z=x+iy$ you can write $z'=(1+i-|z|)z$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{x'}{x}-\frac{y'}{y}=-\frac{y}{x}-\frac{x}{y}.$$

Let $\frac{y}{x}=u.$

Now, we obtain:
$$\left(\ln|u|\right)'=u+\frac{1}{u}.$$